# API MEN(Mysql, expressjs and nodejs)

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have one trouble with an insert because I have the next code:

```
registrar: function(body, callback) {

    var bind = [];

    for (prop in body) {
        bind.push(body[prop]);
    }

    let sql = `INSERT INTO datos_inscripcion
        (ID,NOMBRE_ALUMNO,  FECHA_NACIMIENTO, EDAD, CURP, DIRECCION, NOMBRE_PADRE, EDAD_PADRE, OCUPACION_PADRE, ESCOLARIDAD_PADRE, 
        NOMBRE_MADRE, EDAD_MADRE, OCUPACION_MADRE, ESCOLARIDAD_MADRE, ESCOLARIDAD_TUTOR, NOMBRE_TUTOR, CURP_TUTOR, DOMICILIO_TUTOR, 
        TELEFONO) VALUES 
        (1,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)`;


    // call the query give it the sql string and the values (bind array)
    pool.query(sql, bind, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // return the last inserted id. if there is no error
        callback(result.insertId);
    });
},
```

and the console launch:

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?)' at line 3.
```

So, somebody can explain to me, please.

Comment: How many elements do you have in your `bind` array? Does it match with the number of `?`s?

Comment: Hi, @SebastianKaczmarek 19, but one is id, and this is auto-incremental, so I insert 18 and I confirm the number of rows

Comment: If `id` is auto-incremental, then you don't need to specify it in the `INSERT` query as it will be added automatically. Try removing `ID` from your query, and `1` from the `VALUES` and see if that works.